# Make test failing for Wordnet-Similarity

Tags: makefile, trace, perl-module, similarity, wordnet

I am trying to install Wordnet-Similarity-2.05.
But it fails ath the "make test" step. Could someone Please explain why the "make test" is failing and what i could fix it?

Following are the details, starting from the failed test:

```
t/trace.t ......... 51/132 
#   Failed test at t/trace.t line 141.
#          got: '4'
#     expected: '0'
# lesk: The lines 'Overlaps: 1 x "the"  1 x "small"  1 x "of"  2 x "any"  1 x "in the"  1 x "or"  1 x "resembling the"  1 x "and"  ' and 'Overlaps: 1 x "the"  1 x "small"  1 x "in the"  1 x "or"  1 x "of"  1 x "resembling the"  2 x "any"  1 x "and"  ' differ
t/trace.t ......... 121/132 # Looks like you failed 1 test of 132.
t/trace.t ......... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/132 subtests 
t/vector.t ........ ok   
t/vector_pairs.t .. ok   
t/wn30loop.t ...... ok     
t/wup.t ........... ok     

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/trace.t       (Wstat: 256 Tests: 132 Failed: 1)
Failed test:  76
Non-zero exit status: 1
Files=22, Tests=2027, 134 wallclock secs ( 0.44 usr  0.06 sys + 128.26 cusr  4.94 csys = 133.70 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/22 test programs. 1/2027 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
```

Thanks